# sql extract multiple words from one cell

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that has some text written in it, including serial numbers. What I want to do is to extract the serial numbers , when they exists. I managed to extract only the first one. This works great if there is only one SN in it, otherwise the rest are not shown.

For example I have this:

```
1 {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fprq15\fcharset0 Arial;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs16 HPE Gen8 300GB 6G SAS 10K  \par SN:\tab 2C7713I0VG  \par \tab 2C7713I0WX  \par \tab 2C7712I0HP  \par \tab 2C7713I0WS  \par }  
2 {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fprq15\fcharset0 Arial;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs16 HGST Ultrastar 7K4000 2TB HDD  \par SN:\tab P5JKS38W  \par }  
3 {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fprq15\fcharset0 Arial;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs16 Microsoft Project Standard 2016  \par SN:\tab 3BN8W-YBKJQ-3JF76-GKHVV-PWFPJ  \par ID:\tab ObenAT1d0220  \par }
4 {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fprq15\fcharset0 Arial;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs16 ClientID:\tab AuttechGR0201  \par SN:\tab 737NH-HVYGX-QYTFF-VGDG4-HQWCG  \par }
5 {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fprq15\fcharset0 Arial;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs16 HGST Ultrastar 7K4000 2TB HDD }
```

I need to split the each SN into new row, like this:

```
SerialNumbers
2C7713I0VG
2C7713I0WX
2C7712I0HP
2C7713I0WS
P5JKS38W
3BN8W-YBKJQ-3JF76-GKHVV-PWFPJ
737NH-HVYGX-QYTFF-VGDG4-HQWCG
```

This is what I did so far:

```
SELECT 
ABFPosLangText, 
SUBSTRING(
    ABFPosLangText, 
    CHARINDEX('\par SN:\tab', ABFPosLangText)+ LEN('\par SN:\tab'), --begining of the first serial number
    CHARINDEX('\', ABFPosLangText, CHARINDEX('\par SN:\tab', ABFPosLangText))- CHARINDEX('\par SN:\tab', ABFPosLangText)+ LEN('\par SN:\tab')

FROM ABFPos

 WHERE ABFPosLangText LIKE ('%SN:%')
```

As it can be seen , the serial nums are in between \tab and \par.

**I used \par SN:\tab - because I was trying to get any result**

I am still a newbie when it comes to SQL, so any help would be great.

**EDIT**

using the answer from @Tyron78 I tried to get my result, but it still gives me errors. I do have to point out that I did change the code a little bit because I use MS SQL - instead of TRIM func I used RTRIM(LTRIM()) - which should work - but I still get the first part of the text in the result.

When the query is implemented on the first line I get the following result:

```
SerialNr
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fprq15\fcharset0 Arial;}} \viewkind4\uc1d\f0\fs16 HPE Gen8 300GB 6G SAS 10K  SN:
 2C7713I0VG
 2C7713I0WX
 2C7712I0HP
 2C7713I0WS  }
```

AND this is the msg I get : **Message 9421, level 16, status 1, line 1
XML analysis: line 2, character 48, invalid name character.**

Comment: which database you are using ?

Comment: I am using MSSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use a mixture of XML and CrossApply, such as follows:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
ID int, MyString nvarchar(1000)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, N'{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fprq15\fcharset0 Arial;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs16 HPE Gen8 300GB 6G SAS 10K  \par SN:\tab 2C7713I0VG  \par \tab 2C7713I0WX  \par \tab 2C7712I0HP  \par \tab 2C7713I0WS  \par }')
,(2, N'{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fprq15\fcharset0 Arial;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs16 HGST Ultrastar 7K4000 2TB HDD  \par SN:\tab P5JKS38W  \par }')
,(3, N'{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fprq15\fcharset0 Arial;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs16 HGST Ultrastar 7K4000 2TB HDD}')

;WITH cte1 AS(
SELECT ID, SUBSTRING(MyString, CHARINDEX('SN:', MyString)+3, LEN(MyString)-CHARINDEX('SN:', MyString)-2) AS MyString
  FROM @t
  WHERE CHARINDEX('SN:', MyString) > 0
)
select 
    a.value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS SerialNr
from
    (select cast('<M>' + rtrim(ltrim(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(MyString, '\tab', '</M><M>'),'\par',''),'{',''),'}',''))) + '</M>' AS XML) as col from cte1) as A
    CROSS APPLY A.col.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
where NULLIF(a.value('.', 'varchar(max)'),'') IS NOT NULL
```

However, this will only work if SN is the last part of your string. If anything else follows in the string, you will have to consider this in your substring in cte1.

Comment: Hi , thank you for answering to my question, I tried your answer online and it worked...but when I tried to implement it to my MS SQL server I got the following msg : **"Message 9421, level 16, status 1, line 1
XML analysis: line 3, character 30, invalid name character."** - I thought the problem was because my sql version was old - but it is not; I don't know what the problem is

Comment: Okay, I think I know where the problem is. Some of my lines don't have SN in them. How could I avoid that problem? I did added **WHERE MyString LIKE ('SN')** clause in the first SELECT  - this helped (I get some results), but it still gives me error, probably because I have to change the second part of the Query too. do you have maybe an idea how to correct it ? thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I modified the code a little. I wouldn't use `LIKE` but `CHARINDEX` instead - please retry

Comment: I tried that, but I still get a error msg, this one : **Message 9421, level 16, status 1, line 1
XML analysis: line 2, character 48, invalid name character.** , but I do have to point out that I had to change your **TRIM** function I used RTRIM(LTRIM()) - since MS sql doesn't accept TRIM function :/ and I think because of that I still get the first part of the text as a result. I will update my question so you can see my result

Comment: I use MS SQL as well (SQL Server 2017), so basically it should run.... I will test your change with rtrim / ltrim

Comment: I edited my answer to ltrim / rtrim - works as well on my server... did you use the exactly same set of test data?

Comment: maybe the problem is that the column type is not NVARCHAR but NTEXT ? :/

Comment: I showed only the first two lines, but all of them are like that... only difference between your inputs and mine is that you forgot to add '{}' at the biginning and end of each line. So at the last SN the output has "}" also

Comment: Yes, might be NTEXT... I already added the {} to my answer... I'll investigate the NTEXT, but what is the maximum length of your column?

Comment: I just checked it is 2008. I will also add more input values at my question , in the hopes it will help. and thank you for helping me...I am going nuts over this

Comment: Thank you for your help, I managed to figure out why it was giving me an error, now it works...I just have to fix the problem with the 'ID: ...' when it shows after SN , should be done using SUBSTRING inside of a First replace function